# Format issue when using vba Userform

Tags: vba, excel, format

I have previous made a punch in  clock worksheet in Excel. The normal function of the punch in clock is when I press the punch in button, a macro find time (and date) via the vba inbulid variable Time (and Date) and put them into defined cells. And the same happens, when I punch out, but here it also calculates the daily working hours and a running balance with flextime

This part works fine

I have recently wanted to extend my program, so it is possible to via the vba userform change the time (punch in or out) of a specific date and then recalculate the flextime balance.
It has been possible to get the userform to find and change the time of a specific date, but when I try to recalculate the working hours and flextime, I get a format missing match error. When in debug, I hover over the variable, I can see that the changed cell is formatted as hh:mm:ss, but the the existing cells are formatted as decimal numbers even though, they are display as time in the worksheet.

How can I the formats to be similar?

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
Dim w1 As Worksheet
Set w1 = Sheets("Aktuel måned")

numofDateRows = w1.Range("I1").Offset(w1.Rows.Count - 1, 0).End(xlUp).Row 'find last cell with dates


For i = 1 To numofDateRows
    If w1.Range("I" & i) = DTPicker1 Then 'find row with choosen date
        If chbInd.value = True Then 'if punch in time is going to be change
            w1.Range("J" & i) = txbTid 'inserts the new time
            w1.Range("L" & i) = w1.Range("K" & i) - w1.Range("J" & i) + w1.Range("F12").MergeArea.Cells(1, 1) 'recaculate working hours
            w1.Range("M" & i) = w1.Range("L" & i) + w1.Range("M" & (i - 1)) - w1.Range("F14") 'recalculate flextime balance
        End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: samples of: `w1.Range("I" & i)`, `DTPicker1`, `txbTid` to start off with

Comment: You need to eloborate, what you are asking for?

Comment: I am asking for the data these `w1.Range("I" & i)`, `DTPicker1`, `txbTid` store when your code breaks.

Comment: w1.Range("I" & i) and DTPicker1 holds 01-04-2014. txbTid holds "08:00:00"

Comment: the above is a example, when I pick 01-04-2014 in the DT picker and enter 08:00:00 as the new punch in time fx

Comment: @reuss try getting the `TimeValue` of your changed time such as `w1.RangE("J" & i) = TimeValue(txbTid)`